# How to define a complex recursive sequence in SageMath?

Tags: python, math, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, sage

I am terribly sorry, since my question may seem obvious, but I am struggling right know at defining a complex sequence in SageMath.

`

```
def f(n):                            
        if n == 0:  
                return 1 + 2* I 
        else:
                
                return (2*f(n-1).real() * f(n-1).img())/(f(n-1).real() + f(n-1).img())+ I * sqrt(f(n-1).real() * f(n-1).img())
f(1)
```

`
(code without 'sage:' at the beginning, since I wrote this in jupyter.
As you see, I am trying to define this sequence.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kh1Fa.jpg)

I tried this, but I got the following error:
`

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-18-5ed25076225b> in <module>
      5 
      6                 return (Integer(2)*f(n-Integer(1)).real() * f(n-Integer(1)).img())/(f(n-Integer(1)).real() + f(n-Integer(1)).img())+ I * sqrt(f(n-Integer(1)).real() * f(n-Integer(1)).img())
----> 7 f(Integer(1))

<ipython-input-18-5ed25076225b> in f(n)
      4         else:
      5 
----> 6                 return (Integer(2)*f(n-Integer(1)).real() * f(n-Integer(1)).img())/(f(n-Integer(1)).real() + f(n-Integer(1)).img())+ I * sqrt(f(n-Integer(1)).real() * f(n-Integer(1)).img())
      7 f(Integer(1))

/opt/sagemath-9.3/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sage/structure/element.pyx in sage.structure.element.Element.__getattr__ (build/cythonized/sage/structure/element.c:4709)()
    491             AttributeError: 'LeftZeroSemigroup_with_category.element_class' object has no attribute 'blah_blah'
    492         """
--> 493         return self.getattr_from_category(name)
    494 
    495     cdef getattr_from_category(self, name):

/opt/sagemath-9.3/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sage/structure/element.pyx in sage.structure.element.Element.getattr_from_category (build/cythonized/sage/structure/element.c:4821)()
    504         else:
    505             cls = P._abstract_element_class
--> 506         return getattr_from_other_class(self, cls, name)
    507 
    508     def __dir__(self):

/opt/sagemath-9.3/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sage/cpython/getattr.pyx in sage.cpython.getattr.getattr_from_other_class (build/cythonized/sage/cpython/getattr.c:2618)()
    370         dummy_error_message.cls = type(self)
    371         dummy_error_message.name = name
--> 372         raise AttributeError(dummy_error_message)
    373     attribute = <object>attr
    374     # Check for a descriptor (__get__ in Python)
AttributeError: 'sage.rings.number_field.number_field_element_quadratic.NumberFieldElement_gaussian' object has no attribute 'img'
```

`
So Sage has got some problems with .img() but I am wondering, since this normally works fine.
Does anyone know, how to fix this, or does Sage not support complex sequences.

Answer (score 0):

The imaginary part of a complex number is extracted using the method `imag` - for instance:

```
sage: z = 1 + 2*i
sage: z.imag()
2
```

Or just (implicitly) converting `z` to a tuple is already extracting the real and imaginary parts. But this may introduce a bug in case of `z = 0` or `z = 2023`.

So using (economically calls of `f(n - 1)` inside the definition of `f(n)`, and possibly also catching somehow the case of an `n` not in `ZZ` or of a negative integer in an improved version...):

```
def f(n):                            
    if n == 0:  
        return 1 + 2*i 
    z = f(n - 1)
    x, y = z.real(), z.imag()
    
    return 2*x*y/(x + y) + i*sqrt(x*y)
```

we compute recursively for instance via:

```
for k in [0..2]:
    fk = f(k)
    print(f'f({k}) = {fk} ~ {fk.n()}')
```

the terms:

```
f(0) = 2*I + 1 ~ 1.00000000000000 + 2.00000000000000*I
f(1) = I*sqrt(2) + 4/3 ~ 1.33333333333333 + 1.41421356237310*I
f(2) = 2*I*2^(1/4)*sqrt(1/3) + 8*sqrt(2)/(3*sqrt(2) + 4) ~ 1.37258300203048 + 1.37317809593808*I
```